# Scheduled Backup Delayed

Tags: notification

I often find the notification with the heading "Scheduled Backup Delayed". What does it mean? What can I do so that the notification do not show up?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the deja-dup applet as follows:

deja-dup

Click on Scheduling to set backup frequency or turn it off.

Click on Storage Location. See the 2nd line: change the location of the backup from the storage location in the backup settings of the tool you use to create a backup.

What you currently have set is likely invalid. For instance not a location owned by your user, or even it was never set or it requires a user and password validation.

In case of duplicity:

[image]